# Adding security on routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, routes

In Rails 2, how can I prevent a user from just changing the id # and accessing other Objects?

For example :

```
website.com/users/1231/edit
```

How do I prevent a user from changing the `1231` and accessing another account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `before_filter` in your controllers.

```
class Users < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user, :only => [:show]

  private

  def require_user
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @user.nil?
  end

end
```

Comment: User.find(params[:id]) is fine, you don't need to do find_by_id

Comment: If you use `Users#find` it will throw an exception if it's not found.

Answer (score 8):

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
redirect_to :back unless current_user == @user
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a permissions-checking gem like CanCan or Aegis. Both have conventions that add permissions checking to every method on every controller automatically.

Comment: You have to code the authorization method and also must include it where you want authorizations. Therefore, the amount of code needed for what seems to be one model would be equal or exceeding the fixes above. I am a fan of cancan, but it is overkill in this situation.

Comment: Nowhere is it mentioned to be only one model. There's one model as an example, but there's no reason to assume the OP doesn't want this on every controller. Besides, they may not be aware that the likes of CanCan exist, or of the extended benefits of easy permissions checking they offer.