# Need help with custom authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys I created some custom authentication thanks to railscasts.com but I'm somewhat stuck as I need to restrict my users from editing other users' profiles.

Here's my authenticate_user and current_user methods:

```
private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end

def authenticate_user!
  if current_user.nil?
    redirect_to login_url, :alert => "You must first log in to access this page"
  end
end
```

Here's the before_filter in my **UsersController**:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]`
```

**EDIT:** Fixed it thanks to alock27.

I had to edit my users_controller and modify the edit action as follows:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]    
redirect_to root_url unless current_user == @user
```

Comment: Nope, it's a custom authentication system built using railscasts.com's tutorials :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

[Adding security on routes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820796/adding-security-on-routes-in-rails/6820828#6820828)

you need to find the User by :id and check if current_user = @user

Comment: I did try doing `if current_user == @user` but it does not work.

Comment: sweet, a post in that link fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to provide an id for edit, update and destroy: you already have current_user.
Instead of editing `@user = User.find(id)`, edit `current_user`. Thus, your authentication functions ensure the user will only edit its own profile.

Comment: what prevents changing the url id from users/my_id/edit to users/your_id/edit?

Comment: In the edit method, you will use current_user, and edit only that object. You don't use anymore the id to retrieve the user, because you already got it from the authentication system, and you can change the route to "users/edit".